# `create_or_find_by` not working as it should in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to use [`create_or_find_by`](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/02/23/rails-6-adds-create_or_find_by.html) which is like `find_or_create_by` except it tries the `create` first, and resorts to `find` if there was a uniqueness validation error (at least that's my understanding of what it should do). It has the advantage of being much less likely to be affected by race conditions.

However it doesn't seem to be working:

```rb
class Nation < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

```
> n = Nation.take
=> #<Nation...
> Nation.create_or_find_by(name: n.name).id
=> nil
> Nation.create_or_find_by!(name: n.name).id
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:80:in `raise_validation_error': Validation failed: Name has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It turns out](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36027#issuecomment-485453493) that `create_or_find_by` only swallows `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` errors, which are those triggered by the uniqueness constraint set at the database level. If you also have equivalent uniqueness constraints set at the model level they raise a different error (`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`) before the request goes to the database, and this kind of error is not swallowed. Therefore `create_or_find_by` only works if you've got your uniqueness validation only in the database, not in the model.

This shows that it works when we turn off the model level validation:

```rb
n = Nation.take
validators = Nation._validate_callbacks.select { _1.filter.class == ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator }
validators.each { Nation.skip_callback(_1.name, _1.kind, _1.filter) }
Nation.create_or_find_by!(name: n.name).id # returns the ID of the existing nation as expected
validators.each { Nation.set_callback(_1.name, _1.kind, _1.filter) }
```

I've decided to fix this short-coming in my app by adding this code in `ApplicationRecord.rb`:

```rb
  def self.create_or_find_by(attributes, &block)
    obj = super(attributes, &block)
    unless obj.persisted?
      attribute_names = attributes.keys.map { _1.to_s.delete_suffix('_id') }
      if obj.errors.any? && obj.errors.all? { _1.type == :taken && _1.attribute.to_s.delete_suffix('_id').in?(attribute_names) }
        obj = find_by!(attributes)
      end
    end
    obj
  end

  def self.create_or_find_by!(attributes, &block)
    obj = create_or_find_by(attributes, &block)
    obj.save! unless obj.persisted?
    obj
  end
```

Now `create_or_find_by` works as I think it ought to (at least it does in my app)